# Importing Excel file to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x

New to coding and Jupyter Notebook. Can someone please explain how to import an Excel file to Jupyter Notebook so I can use the commands in Jupyter to filter the information.

I tried this code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Lee Kuo\OneDrive\School\Analytics Computing for Data Science\Module 1 Report\Codes.cvs', sheet_name= 'Olympics')
```

this is the error I got

> File "", line 2 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Lee Kuo\OneDrive\School\Analytics Computing for Data Science\Module 1 Report\Codes.cvs', sheet_name= 'Olympics'

I believe the issue is I'm not finding the folder correctly

Comment: It's probably dependent on your Jupyter platform. Does this help? https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+read+excel+file+in+jupyter+notebook

Comment: this is the error(below) I got when following the direction. I believe the issue is I'm not finding the folder correctly.

 File "<ipython-input-1-dc00e14ba129>", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Lee Kuo\OneDrive\School\Analytics Computing for Data Science\Module 1 Report\Codes.cvs', sheet_name= 'Olympics'

Comment: There is some confusion here. Are you importing a CSV file or an excel (.xlsx) file? They are different files and use different methods. If it is a CSV filem it would be unexpected for it to be called Codes.CVS. Are you certain you entered the path right? It looks like a tutorial. Can you just link to the tutorial to give some context? There are many different type of Jupyter notebooks and we need to know your setup to help.

Comment: Apologize for the confusion. I am trying to import a file from Excel but it's save under CSV so its a CSV file. I followed the instructions from this tutorial https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+read+excel+file+in+jupyter+notebook. The path was copied from the detail part of the file.
I am using a Jupyter Notebook with Python3 and I dont know much else about the program as I'm new to this. Hope this was enough information.

Comment: I have edited your question based on your comment and made some assumptions. This is the level of detail you really need to show. But it's still inconsistent. according to the doc, `read_csv` doesn't have a parameter called `sheet_name`. Which makes sense because csv files do not have sheets. So in the first instance remove that. In the second instance, make 100% sure that you have a file called that in that location. Does it _really_ end in `.cvs`? That seems like a typo. Lastly, try moving the file somewhere else like `C:\temp` and see if it works.

Comment: After moving the file into the same folder as where my Jupyter programs are the file imported. Thanks for your help @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Which makes sense because csv files do not have sheets. So in the first instance remove that." Well, that can be a real problem, if someone wants to work with just one sheet of an Excel file with multiple sheets. I was under the impression that was what the question was about.